# Quarkus application deployed on Heroku gives Error R10 (Boot Timeout)

Tags: java, docker, heroku, quarkus

I'm having issues deploying a Quarkus 1.10 application to Heroku as a Docker image.

The same application, using SpringBoot and a similar Docker Image boots successfully, but somehow Quarkus triggers the infamous R10 Boot Timeout error due to bad bind of $PORT, even when I see that the boot times are really small (2 seconds vs. 4.5 of the SpringBoot version).
If I start the image locally, it works perfectly without issues.

My final Docker Image is like this (omitting the Multi-stage build steps for brevity):

```
FROM gcr.io/distroless/java:11
ENV QUARKUS_MAILER_FROM=${EMAIL_USERNAME} \
    QUARKUS_MAILER_USERNAME=${EMAIL_USERNAME} \
    QUARKUS_MAILER_PASSWORD=${EMAIL_PASSWORD}
EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=backend /usr/src/app/target/*-runner.jar /usr/app/app.jar
COPY --from=backend /usr/src/app/target/lib /usr/app/lib
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar" ]
CMD ["/usr/app/app.jar", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0", "-Dquarkus.http.port=${PORT}"]
```

I'm using the commands to deploy the application:

```
heroku container:push web
heroku container:release web
```

I don't see where the error is. I've also tried to remove the `EXPOSE` directive from the Dockerfile but that's not the cause of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue, which is really dumb.

Modifying the ENTRYPOINT and the CMD sections of the Dockerfile as follows:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "java" ]
CMD ["-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0", "-Dquarkus.http.port=${PORT}", "-jar", "/usr/app/app.jar"]
```

it works. The problem is, the system properties have to be passed *before* the `-jar` parameter, otherwise Quarkus doesn't pick the right value for ${PORT}